# I want to apply a filter in composite chart on the legends click in DC.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

[This is my composite chart with bar and linear chart attached to it by custom method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8xXQ.png)

I want to click on one of those legends (ex: Negative) and it should filter based on that sentiment only, expecting only a red line be shown and all other dc chart filter based on this. tried something like this on composite but couldn't get it right..

```
var dateDimension = cf.dimension(function (d) { if (d.dd) { return d3.time.day(d.dd) } else { return d3.time.day() } });

                            var negativeSentimentGroup = dateDimension.group().reduceSum(function (d) { return d.sentiment === 'negative' ? 1 : 0; });
                            var positiveSentimentGroup = dateDimension.group().reduceSum(function (d) { return d.sentiment === 'positive' ? 1 : 0; });
                            var neutralSentimentGroup = dateDimension.group().reduceSum(function (d) { return d.sentiment === 'neutral' ? 1 : 0; });

                            var minDate = dateDimension.bottom(1)[0].dd;
                            minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() - 1);

                            var maxDate = dateDimension.top(1)[0].dd;
                            maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate() + 1);
                            // Group comments count by date

                            var dateDimensionGroup = dateDimension.group().reduceCount();

// Plot for Daily progress of comments
                            var sentimentSeriesChart = dc.compositeChart("#sentiment-series", groupName);

                            sentimentSeriesChart.on('pretransition.hideshow', function (chart) {
                                chart.selectAll('g.dc-legend .dc-legend-item')
                                    .on('click.hideshow', function (d, i) {
                                        $scope.lineChange(d.name);
                                    });
                            });
                            var negativeSeriesChart = dc.lineChart(sentimentSeriesChart).group(negativeSentimentGroup, "Negative").colors('red');
                            var positiveSeriesChart = dc.lineChart(sentimentSeriesChart).group(positiveSentimentGroup, "Positive").colors('green');
                            var neutralSeriesChart = dc.lineChart(sentimentSeriesChart).group(neutralSentimentGroup, "Neutral").colors('orange');
                            var timeBarChart = dc.barChart(sentimentSeriesChart).group(dateDimensionGroup).centerBar(true);

                            sentimentSeriesChart.width(1000)
                                .height(200)
                                .margins({ top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 60, left: 40 })
                                .dimension(dateDimension)
                                .transitionDuration(500)
                                .brushOn(true)
                                .title(function (d) {
                                    return chartingDateFormat(d.key) + ' : ' + d.value;
                                })
                                .legend(dc.legend().autoItemWidth(true).x(450).y(180).horizontal(true).itemHeight(16).gap(80).maxItems(3))
                                .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
                                .compose([
                                    negativeSeriesChart,
                                    positiveSeriesChart,
                                    neutralSeriesChart,
                                    timeBarChart
                                ])
                                .elasticY(true)
                                .yAxisLabel("No. of Comments")
                                .x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate, maxDate]))
                                .xUnits(function () { return 90; })
                                .xAxis().tickFormat(d3.time.format("%d/%m"));

                            // Set number of ticks
                            sentimentSeriesChart.yAxis().ticks(5);
```

In the above piece of code i'm able to get the click event on Legend (ex: Negative) and on that I'm filtering my data set with only Negative comment and the doing , cf.remove(); (where cf is cross filter instance ) and adding the new filtered data set - cf.add(filterData); and redrawing the complete dc group - dc.redrawAll(groupName);

By this i'm able to filter the data but the date range in composite chart is showing incorrect,,

[This is the result I'm getting after after the Legend button click on composite chart (for example : Negative )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6CeG.png)